# Regulating 4 AA batteries to 5V over the discharge cycle of the batteries?

Tags: power, batteries, dc-dc-converter

Over the discharge lifetime of these batteries the voltage might range from 6V down to 4V.

If the batteries were consistently over/under 5V, I could use a step up/step down converter such as a MCP1640/LM2623.

How can I design my circuit such that 5V will be delivered consistently over the entire input range of the AA cells?

Comment: I've no idea what kind of load current you need (you don't write it out), but isn't this a classic case of a 'buck/boost' system? (Like [this IC](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/412/ACT5101_Data_Sheet-1714862.pdf) achieves, but perhaps without all the extra stuff there.) Or am I missing something?

Comment: Here's [another one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf?ts=1693818554702&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS63070%252Fpart-details%252FTPS63070RNMT%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Docb-tistore-promo-app_opn_en-cpc-storeic-google-eu%2526utm_content%253DDevice%2526ds_k%253DTPS63070RNMT%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQjwgNanBhDUARIsAAeIcAsDbtDXm-WvB2MgYAsIQvHo5xSnblS1mET2mSY6ggqGlCt2nehI7KgaAjGjEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) from TI. I don't deal in these things. So I can't say what's commonly used.

Comment: Use a converter as other mention. Another option is a charge pump if it is going about small loads. Charge pumps are more efficient at light loads.

Comment: If you can use 5 x AA batteries then a buck or linear regulator becomes viable. YOu knew that :-). 2 x LiIon similarly. || For interest: AA Alkaline start at about 1.65V each when factory new so about 6.6V for 4. This drops with time to typically around 1.6V after 1 to 2 years - brand dependant.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Thanks for reminding me I knew that!! And you know what else I knew and also forgot? "Double check the data sheets to verify operating voltage"... which I did, and happily discovered that the 5V devices I'm using actually will run of 3.3V, which brings the number of batteries back down to four.  Hooray and thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is what buck-boost converters are for. There are a number of topologies; the most basic one outputs a voltage of opposite polarity to its input, but if that's not workable you can also use a SEPIC (aka a two-coil or two-inductor buck-boost) or a four-switch buck-boost (which is basically just a buck converter and a boost converter that share an inductor, and activate whichever converter is needed at the time).